# change state on single li react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i add class to single `li` element using `onClick`? At the moment when i click on whatever `li`, all `div`'s are getting `item-active` class when `state` is changed.

I do have `index` from mapped array, but i'm not sure where (i believe in `handleClick()`?) should i use it to make it working...

```
//import {cost} from '...';
export class CostFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {active: "item-not-active"};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(){
    let isActive = this.state.active === "item-not-active" ? "item-active" : "item-not-active";
    this.setState({active: isActive});
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
          {cost.map((element, index) =>
              <li onClick={this.handleClick}  value={`cost-${element.cost}`} key={index}>
                  <div className={`hs icon-${element.cost} ${this.state.active}`}></div>
              </li>
          )}
        </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
export class CostFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeIndex: null};
  }
  handleClick(index) {
    let activeIndex = this.state.activeIndex === index ? null : index;
    this.setState({activeIndex});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {cost.map((element, index) =>
          <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}  value={`cost-${element.cost}`} key={index}>
            <div className={`
                   hs 
                   icon-${element.cost} 
                   ${this.state.activeIndex === index && 'item-active'}
                 `}></div>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is is possible to use `element` instead of the index?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, don't see the benefit though.

Comment: Would be possible to add sorting and remove and add items.

Comment: Indeed that worked, had to take time to understand how everything works. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can store index of the clicked element in the state of your component and then check in your render function in map if the current index is equal to the key in the state. Something like this :

```
let data = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', "Item 3"];

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state = {
           active: null
        }
    }

    handleClick(i){ 
       this.setState({active: i});
    }

    render(){
       return <ul>{this.props.data.map((item, i) => <li key={i} className={this.state.active === i ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)}>{item}</li>)}</ul>
    }
}

React.render(<Test data={data}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1450/).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what are you looking for. [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1447/)

```
const data = ['Hello', 'World']

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
        isActive: -1
    }
  }
    click(key,e){
    this.setState({
        isActive: key
    })
  }
    render(){
    const costsList = this.props.costs.map((item, key) => {
        return <li key={key} 
            className={this.state.isActive === key ? 'foo' : ''}
            onClick={this.click.bind(this, key)}>
            {item}
       </li>
    })
    return <ul>
        {costsList}
    </ul>
  }
}

React.render(<Example costs={data}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to simplify this with React Hooks ( check example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ahmedyounes/pen/qwpBvQ) )

```
const MyApp = (props)=>{
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(null)

  let activeStyle = {backgroundColor:"red", width:"400px", height:"22px", margin: "2px"}
  let normalStyle = {backgroundColor:"blue", width:"400px", height:"22px", margin: "2px"}

  const handleClick = (i)=>{
    setActiveIndex(i)
  }


  let output= ["item-1", "item-2", "item-3", "item-4", "item-5", "item-6", "item-7", "item-8", "item-9", "item-10"];


  return(
    <div>
    {output.map((v, i)=>{
        return (
          <li key={i} style={activeIndex === i ? activeStyle: normalStyle}>
            {i} : {v}
            <button onClick={()=>handleClick(i)} name={i}>Change background color</button>
          </li>)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]